# Stopping Background Music when Returning (Focus in) to Adobe AIR Application (iOS)

Tags: ios, air, avaudioplayer, air-native-extension

I'm using AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback (via an Adobe AIR iOS Native Extension) when my application starts to stop playback of background music (for example Spotify) when entering my app.

This works well when my Application starts, but when its resumed (switched from the background to the foreground) it doesn't.

Is there anything special to set to have my application get control of the Audio Session when resuming?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with iOS ignoring audio-related native extensions if you'd minimise the app and then open it again. I'm not sure if there's an official or more efficient solution, but what I did was listen for every time the app is opened (add a listener to the stage for Event.ACTIVATE) and then re-activate the native extension. Hope that works for you.